# Find all integers $k$ such that $5^k\equiv 97 \pmod{101}$

Tags: number-theory, congruences

Find integers $k$ such that $5^k\equiv 97 \pmod{101}$.

By brutal force, If $k=23$ then $101\vert 5^{23}-97$. Furthermore, by Euler-Fermat theorem, since $gcd(5,101)$ we have, $5^{100}\equiv 1\pmod{101}$, then for integer $r$, $5^{100r}\equiv 1\pmod{101}$, so $5^{100r+23}\equiv 97\pmod{101}$, but I'm not sure if this is true, any other idea of how find all intergers k. Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your question is?

Comment: Find integers $k$ such that $5^k\equiv 97\mod(101)$

Comment: I guess you mean find ALL the integers?  Also, are you sure that $101 | 5^{16}-97$?

Comment: Oh sorry, since the numbers are so big, the calculator approached the values of division.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a typo but $5^{100r + 23} = 97 \mod 101$ not $1 \mod 101$.  Once$ 5^{100} = 1$ Try $5^{50} $ and $5^25$ you find $5^25 = 1$ so $5^{25r + 23} = 97$.

Comment: To *not* use brute force not 97 = -4 and -4*25 = -100 = 1.  So $5^{-2} \equiv 97 \mod 101$. (That is $k -2$ where $5^k = 1$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$97 \equiv -4 \mod 101$.  $-4 * 25 = -100 \equiv 1 \mod 101$.

So if $5^k \equiv 1 \mod 101$ then $5^{k -2} \equiv 97 \mod 101$.

Now $5^{100} \equiv 1 \mod 101$ as 101 is prime so $\phi (101) = 100$ so $5^{\phi(101)} \equiv 1 \mod 101$.

$5^{100} \equiv 1 \mod 101$.  So try $5^{50}$ and $5^{25}$ and we see $5^{25} \equiv 1 \mod 101$.  If there is any smaller power so that $5^n \equiv 1 \mod 101$ it would be $5$.  But $5^5 \equiv 95 \equiv -6 \mod 101$.

So $5^{25} \equiv 1 \mod 101$ so $5^{25-2} = 5^{23} \equiv 97 \mod 101$.

so $k = 25r + 23$ are all the integers such that $5^k \equiv 97 \mod 101$.

Comment: Oh.  Damn typo.  I meant 97; not 1 (of course)

Answer (score 1):

The only such $k$ are $k = 23 + 25n$ for all integers $n$.

Proof: First, check that it works for $k=23.$  Next, suppose $k'$ is another, larger integer that works.  Then $5^{k-k'}$ would be 1 modulo 101, but this means that $k-k'$ is a multiple of 25, since 25 is the order of 5 in the group of units modulo 101 (i.e. 25 is the LEAST power $m$ such that $5^m \equiv 1 (\mod 101)$).

Comment: Not entirely true  25, not 100, is the order of 5. $k = 23 + 25n$ or $k = 25n - 2$ work as $5^{25} = 1 \mod 101$.

Comment: How do you figure 100 is the "LEAST" such power?  It isn't.  25 is.

Comment: thanks for the catch.  I'll fix

Answer (score 0):

I may have calculated this incorrectly.  Please check. I used a Google sheet with three columns.

The first column, A, contained the integers from 1 to 100 as counters.

The second column, B, contained the formula =mod(B\$1*B1,E\$1) starting with the second row.  The cell B\$1 contained 5.  I copied this formula for counters in A between 2 and 100.

The third column, C, contained a conditional formula to alert me if a solution existed.  The formula =if(B1=G\$1,"true","") was copied to all the cells with the value in A between 2 and 100.

The cell E\$1 contained the modulus 101.

The cell G\$1 contained the desired residue 97.

By this calculation, there are four solutions modulo 100, namely, k equal 23, 48, 73 and 98.  The order of 5 modulo 101 is 25.

Comment: "there are four solutions modulo 101": that should be modulo 100, because $\varphi(101) = 100$ (and so $5^{100}\equiv 1 \bmod 101$).

Comment: Thanks.  I made the correction.